# port number for inputting as parameters to my python program

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, redmon

My program is accepting 3 parameters

Port for the script to listen on (default: 9100)
IP-Address to redirct the print job to after saving to a file
Destination port to use when forwarding on print jobs (default: 9100)

It is required to fetch data from the port and forward it to destination printer port using its IP address.
I need help in figuring out the port number of destination printer I should be inputting.I know the printer,its IP from printer properties.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see Python listed when you select "Run As"? 
Did you select the Python interpreter?

To configure your Eclipse follow these tips: [How to Configure Eclipse for Python](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm)

Comment: I have configured eclipse for python and also added the python interpreter in the windows->preference->pydev->interpreter python,but it still shows me select ant builder in the run as window.Is their no other way to run the **prn2me** code?using python shell when I run this code it shows syntax error.but this code is available on net and must not  have any errors.not once i could find.

Comment: PYTHON dnt appear when i clicked run as.their is no option under run as it just says **none applicable**

Comment: can you try running  the script sir,in python shell.and see what error is there?because i dnt find any error.

Comment: Are you sure you have Python installed? Try uninstalling and installing again. Look, also some incompatibility of version 3.0, as this is very problematic.

Comment: i configured it again.it still tells me the same.can u tell me how to run the code in notepad++ or python shell

Answer (score 0):

In order to run python code in eclipse you need to install the pydev plugin for elcipse which can be found on [pydev.org](http://pydev.org/), and there is a good documentation on it's website on how to install and configure it.

after that you have to create a pydev project in eclipse and run your code using the Python interpreter and not ant build. ant build is something related to java. it has nothing to do with python code.